# Where did the texture fill option go in QGIS 1.9 Master?

Tags: qgis, cartography, style

In the previous version (1.8) of QGIS you could select to fill a polygon using a PNG or JPG image.  This option seems to have gone from QGIS 1.9 Master.  I can get it by selecting the "Old Symbology" button on the Style tab.  That's OK but surely this option has not been deprecated (or has it)?

Can anybody tell me where the fill by image option has disappeared to because the only other option I appear to have is SVG fill (SVG is very nice, but I also want the flexibility of using a PNG or JPG is that is what I have to hand) - or perhaps the option only exists as the 'old symbology'.  Also, does anybody know if it is intended to only allow filling polygons with SVG as opposed to PNG/JPG in the future?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know and according to the [documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/html/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#the-vector-properties-dialog) new symbology only supports SVGs while old symbology only supported JPG, XPM and PNG.

I don't know if PNG/JPG support is currently planned. If there is funding, we'll see it. But such information can be best asked on the mailing list.